# Netbeans creates file, then complains it already exists

Tags: c++, class, netbeans

I am trying to create  a new C++ class in Netbeans, by right-clicking on the virtual 'Source Files' folder inside Netbeans, and clicking on 'New C++ Class'.

I name the source file test.cpp and the header file test.hpp. When I click finish, Netbeans complains test.hpp already exists.

I go to /home//NetBeansProjects/ and I can see Netbeans did create the file test.hpp. I delete it, try to create a new class again, and same error occurs. Netbeans did create the file again. (The file does not show up in Netbeans, only in the file browser.

I'm running a Linux Ubuntu-based distribution. Netbeans v7.3.1.

EDIT: This happens with all kinds of files. (Source, Header, Class, C Source, C Class...)